# When are allocated variables of an access type released in Ada language?

Tags: pointers, ada

I'm reading about the Ada `access types` and, as far as I understand, the objects of `access types` that you allocate with the operator `new` are released when no one is pointing to them anymore:

So, do access types in Ada behaves exactly as `std::shared_ptr` in C++? (Apart from the Ada's pointer-related constraints that C++ doesn't have)

## EDIT

When I say `std::shared_ptr` I mean the object is deallocated when there are no more variable pointing to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers are **allowed** to implement garbage collection, but I don't know of any compilers which actually do it (besides some custom builds of GNAT).

You will have to wait for a C++ programmer to pass by, to get a comparison with `std::shared_ptr` from C++.

If you want to ensure that an object allocated in a storage pool (on the heap) is deallocated, you use `Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation`.

Answer (score 0):

No, Ada pointers are (in practice) pretty much unmanaged as C/C++ plain pointers. As Jacob's answer says, that's a compiler implementation choice that I haven't seen in practice.

The difference I know of is, for a locally scoped *pointer type*, you get the memory from all objects of the type back when the *type*, not the pointee, goes out of scope. But these pointers are rarely useful (they can be for very localized algorithms, but not for long lived structures).

For pointers a-la std::shared_ptr you'll need to roll your own implementation or fish for some Ada library out there (probably GNATCOLL.Refcount is a match).

Comment: Storage for an access type is only guaranteed to be reclaimed when the type goes out of scope if the type has Storage_Size specified for it.